# Google tag manager still showing in pagespeed insights after removing script in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to speed up my wordpress site, and at the end of the day we don't really use google tag manager. So I removed the connection in google site kit and also deleted the script tags in the head and body. however, pagespeed insights and the developer console still show the script, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any ideas on how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have a cache plugin activated, try to clean your cache and verify again.